# Python Regex: Get specific text within larger block of text, while skipping some lines

Tags: python, regex, string

As the title mentions, my goal is to get a specific section of text from within a larger block of text. This "parent text" will always be different, but the specific "child" text I am seeking is always formatted the same.

Here is a made up example of the block of text (some may recognize it has wiki markup)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
blah blah
* example
** example 2

= Title =

* [[GARY]]: description
* [[BOB]]: title
* [[JAKE]]: blahblah
* [[SALLY]]: text
* [[JOHN]]: text

blah blah blah 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Within Python, I would like to use some sort of regex that follows these steps:

1. Find "= Title ="
2. Skip the one blank line
3. Grab all text, until you encounter the next blank line

That way the output would be just:

```
* [[GARY]]: description
* [[BOB]]: title
* [[JAKE]]: blahblah
* [[SALLY]]: text
* [[JOHN]]: text
```

I've fooled around with regex101.com but have unable to get anything following that above ruleset. It's possible regex isn't even the right tool for this job but I have been unable to find anything else that seems like it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "child" format is always the same, we can achieve what you've described with a simple regex. You just have to capture all between "\n\n" after `= Title =`:

```py
re.search(r'^=\sTitle\s=\n\n(.*?)(\n\n)', string, re.M | re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

Comment: This looks great. It works perfectly on my provided example, but weirdly enough not on the actual data. On the actual data it is grabbing the next line after the expected output, even though the formatting is the same. Is it because in the actual data, instead of 'blah blah blah' it has some other characters, i.e. html markup <i>example</i>

Comment: @redskins1234, This regex should correctly process a text in format "= Title =\n\n<some text>\n\n". Check your data more carefully and make sure it has the same format.

Comment: @redskins1234, Got it, my bad. Capturing text should work non-greedy (we should add "?"). Edited my answer.